# Does Open Method in Python Executes an EXE

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wonder if `open(file_name, "rb") as binary_file: pass` does actually executes a file if it's exe? I am asking because I am reading some malicious files and viruses using Python stored as ".exe" files.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't AND the flags 'rb' in your open statement stand for read binary. So it's only reading the file and putting it in a byte like object. So not only is it not executing (because that's not a function of open) it's only going to be opened in read mode.

You can read about the open function in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: @Abraheem don't confuse `file.open`, in a programming language, with `file open` in an OS.  You'd have a very hard time writing code to run an EXE directly from within a program, to do that in Python you'd have to call some form of `os.open(<path>)` or `subprocess.open(<path>)`.

Comment: sorry, `os.system`, not `os.open`